# IS there a way to get the pid of a process started using a batch file?

Tags: python, batch-file

So today I started a fun project. I want to be able to start and stop a minecraft server using a discord bot. To start the server I decided to use a batch file to execute the command. This was simple enough to make and I was able to verify that it worked as I could run it and join the 'localhost' server.

Next step was creating a discord bot in Python, I have done that before and that didn't take me long either. I was able to verify on a test discord server I made that the bot responded to commands.

The final step was making the discord bot's commands for starting and stopping the server. I was able to use the `subprocess` library to call the batch file and start the server.

My difficulty is with closing the server. I was planning on using the subprocess' pid to kill it when the right command was run. However I ran into an issue with gaining the pid of the server as subprocess.pid() gets me the pid of the batch file (I think). When I connect to the server after trying to end it, I am able to connect.

Is there a way to gain the pid of a process started with a batch file? If you need to see code or the batch file, just let me know!

I also tried running the command that the batch file runs directly but am struggling with permissions, so if that is a better solution im not sure.

Comment: You can also use imagename.  For example: ‘taskkill /f /im server.xxx’.  Also, if you’re struggling with perms; have you tried running the console in Admin mode?

Comment: do you mean processes started by the same cmd session?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find subprocesses started by the same batch/cmd instance as the current one you can use WMI and [getCmdPID.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat) which will return the current pid of the cmd in the errorlevel:

```
call getCmdPID
wmic path Win32_Process  where ParentProcessId='%errorlevel%' get
```

if it is in a different cmd instance you can start the server with WMIC in order to get the started process PID:

```
WMIC process call create "c:\some.exe","c:\exec_dir"
```

and redirect the output to a file that you can read later.

Comment: So I guess I have a few questions about your answer. would I ```call getCmdPID``` in the same batch file that started the server?

Comment: @UnboltingZero0 - yes. And you can save the PIDs of the subprocesses in some files in order to get them later.